# Redirect to login page if not login magento

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, controllers, login

I want to restrict the visitors for a single store in multistore website. 
If they are not logged in, redirect them to login page.
They can also create account and login after they visit the website. If anyone have idea please let me know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a module for that.

First you need to declare an observer on the `controller_action_predispatch` event: `app/code/local/Vendor/Module/etc/config.xml`

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Vendor_Module>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Vendor_Module>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <module>Vendor_Module_Model</module>
        </models>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <controller_action_predispatch>
                <observers>
                    <vendor_module_controller_action_predispatch>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>module/observer</class>
                        <method>preDispatch</method>
                    </vendor_module_controller_action_predispatch>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_predispatch>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Then in `app/code/local/Vendor/Module/Model/Observer.php` please **note that you need to replace `STORE_ID` with the id of the store you want to implement that feature** :

```
<?php

class Vendor_Module_Model_Observer {

    public function preDispatch(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $controller = $observer->getControllerAction();

        if (Mage::app()->getStore()->getId() == STORE_ID) {

            if ('customer' === $controller->getRouteName()) {
                return $this;
            }

            if (!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->authenticate($controller)) {
                $controller->setFlag('', 'no-dispatch', true);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And `app/etc/modules/Vendor_Module.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Vendor_Module>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Magento_Customer/>
            </depends>
        </Vendor_Module>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Comment: Thanks It works but according to my question we have to modify the observer function like Maurius Posted

Answer (score 2):

You can create an observer for the event `controller_action_predispatch`.
The observer method can look like this:

```
public function redirectNotLogged(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId(); 
    $restrictedStoreId = your restricted store id here. It can even come from a config setting.
    if ($storeId == $restrictedStoreId) {
    $action = strtolower(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getActionName());
        $controller = strtolower(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getControllerName());
        $openActions = array(
            'create',
            'createpost',
            'login',
            'loginpost',
            'logoutsuccess',
            'forgotpassword',
            'forgotpasswordpost',
            'resetpassword',
            'resetpasswordpost',
            'confirm',
            'confirmation'
        );
        if ($controller == 'account' && in_array($action, $openActions)) {
            return $this; //if in allowed actions do nothing.
        }
        if(! Mage::helper('customer')->isLoggedIn()){
            Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('customer/account/login'));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your observer function working thanks for help

Answer (score -1):

Magento 2

```
<?php
namespace BA\GiftCertificate\Controller\CustAccount;
 
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class Index implements \Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory
     */
    protected $resultRedirect;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
     */
    protected $customerSession;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory $resultRedirect
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
     */
    public function __construct(
        RedirectFactory $resultRedirect,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        Session $customerSession
    ) {
        $this->resultRedirect = $resultRedirect;
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    }
    /**
     * Default customer account page
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        if (!$this->customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
            /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirect->create();
            $resultRedirect->setPath('customer/account/login');
            return $resultRedirect;
        } else {
            return $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Question relates to M1.