# Redirect user to login page from store Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, frontend, login

I'm trying to rediect the user to login page after the store is opened the url for the store is

e.g mysiteabc.com/store1

I want the user redirect to login page if he/she visits the store 1 
I am trying this code as [Reference](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/121221/redirect-to-login-page-if-not-login-magento) but it doesnot work for me . Tell me What i'm doing wrong here

**config.xml**

```
 <frontend>
     <events>
         <controller_action_predispatch>
             <observers>
                 <client_controller_action_predispatch>
                     <type>singleton</type>
                     <class>Vendor_Module_Model_Observer</class>
                     <method>preDispatch</method>
                 </client_controller_action_predispatch>
             </observers>
         </controller_action_predispatch>
     </events>
</frontend>
```

**Observer.php**

```
class Vendor_Module_Model_Observer {
    public function preDispatch(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $controller = $observer->getControllerAction();
        if (Mage::app()->getStore()->getId() == STORE_ID) {

            if ('customer' === $controller->getRouteName()) {
                return $this;
            }

            if (!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->authenticate($controller)) {
                $controller->setFlag('', 'no-dispatch', true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that `mysiteabc.com/store1` works ?

Comment: Yes it is loading the store

Comment: In your reference comments says that it worked but with Marius code below not the accepted answer, so try the redirect method it should work.

Comment: Did you replace STORE_ID with the actual store ID?